# Help with a puzzle from an old book

Tags: puzzle

I found a very nice puzzle from a old book written in Spanish.
I got stuck after a few hours, the only possible solution I found was that the numbers inside the circle have a kind of succession.

[image]

For instance:
We have 20 in the first circle, then 15 and 16.
So, I thought that 20 and 16 are divisors of 4, and the number is decreasing from 20 to 16. For this reason, I can think that for 15, the next value is gonna be 12. In conclusion, the letter B (Not E because the first number start from the square of number 1).

But I don't think that my solution could be true.

Do you have any ideas or hints to solve this puzzle? Or maybe you think that my solution was correct?

Comment: I wouldn't see the numbers in the circle as a two digit number, I would see them as two individual numbers.  All the numbers in the puzzle are less than $10$  What do you think the line under the $6$ means in the third figure?  There is no line under the $9$s in the possible answers.

Comment: So Ross, in your questions about the line under 6. Sorry, but I can't see a pattern in the lines. Do you mean that the six is turned? So this becomes into 9?

Comment: You can also ask this question in https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh thanks @farruhota, I didn't know that stachexchange. I gonna ask there.

Comment: After a lot of time Ross, finally I could see the line under 6, and I don't know what that means! :/